# Google App Engine Python Webapp2 301 redirect from www to non-www domain

Tags: python, google-app-engine, seo, webapp2, no-www

I have an application built on gae. I use python with webapp2 framework. I need to make 301 redirect from *www.my-crazy-domain.com* to *my-crazy.domain.com* so to eliminate www and not-www doubles in search results.

Does anybody have ready-to-use solution? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'v made the trick.

```
class BaseController(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   """
   Base controller, all contollers in my cms extends it
   """

    def initialize(self, request, response):
        super(BaseController, self).initialize(request, response)
        if request.host_url != config.host_full:
            # get request params without domain
            url = request.url.replace(request.host_url, '')
            return self.redirect(config.host_full+url, permanent=True)
```

config.host_full contains my primary domain without www. Solution is to check request in base controller and made redirect if domain differs.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution (and not deleting it like someone else said!), this helped me! :)

Answer (score 2):

A solution where you don't need to modify your main application and which also works with static files is to create a service which runs on www. For that create the following files:

`www.yaml`:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
service: www

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: redirectwww.app
```

`redirectwww.py`:

```
import webapp2

class RedirectWWW(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.redirect('https://example.com' + self.request.path)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('.*', RedirectWWW),
])
```

`dipatch.yaml`:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "www.example.com/*"
    service: www
```

Then deploy with `gcloud app deploy www.yaml dispatch.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks! This is quite useful for Single Page Applications, ie. ReactJS apps that have files served via static_files.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How can I test this one before using it on production?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified a bit @userlond answer to not require extra config value, instead I'm using regex:

```
import re
import webapp2


class RequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, request, response):
        super(RequestHandler, self).initialize(request, response)
        match = re.match('^(http[s]?://)www\.(.*)', request.url)
        if match:
            self.redirect(match.group(1) + match.group(2), permanent=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a simpler way using the default get() request. Please enhance the regex if it is possible for the url to have www in places like query params.

```
import re
import webapp2


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        url = self.request.url

        if ('www.' in url):
            url = re.sub('www.', '', url)
            return self.redirect(url, permanent=True)

        self.response.write('No need to redirect')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=False)
```