# How do I redirect www to non-www in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, redirect

My domain is bought from Godaddy and migrated to Amazon AWS. Previously we were using AWS and hosted our static website in AWS bucket but recently we moved to Google cloud platform and hosted our static website and wp blog in app engine. We manage our DNS in Amazon Route 53 and point dns to GAE. The problem is that our website can be browsed with both www and non www domain. Here, We wanted to redirect all the www to non-www domain. This cannot be done in Route 53 because we have pointed dns to GAE and added example.com as A record and www.example.com as CNAME. Thus this also doesn't solves the problem. We are not much sure how to write code in app.yaml file to redirect. We have searched a lot but haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332234/google-app-engine-python-webapp2-301-redirect-from-www-to-non-www-domain

Comment: How can this be done in static website where there is not controller?